# select com pdo em funçoes

Tags: php, pdo

Como faço para usar meu select que esta na minha `funções.php` nesta tabela que esta na minha `estoque.php` , eu já fiz o script só não consigo chamar o `$resultado` que esta na função para usar no `foreach`.

ESTOQUE.PHP

```
    selecionar_produtos();

?>  

<div class="container">
    <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>

            <tr>

                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>Marca</th>
                <th>Modelo</th>
                <th>Quantidade</th>
                <th>Estado</th>
                <th>Opções</th>

            </tr>

        </thead>

        <tbody>

        <?php foreach ($resultado as $key) :?>

            <tr>

                <td><?php echo $key->nome;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $key->marca;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $key->modelo;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $key->quantidade;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $key->estado;?></td>
                <td>
                    <a href="mysql/update.php?id=<?php echo $key->id; ?>" class="btn btn-info">Editar</a>

                    <a href="mysql/delete.php?id=<?php echo $key->id; ?>" class="btn btn-danger">Deletar</a>

                </td>

            </tr>

            <?php endforeach;?>
```

FUNCOES.PHP

```
    <?php

    function selecionar_produtos(){

    require "mysql/pdo.php";

    try{

        $selecionar = "select * from estoqueprodutos . produtos";

        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($selecionar);

        $stmt->execute();

        $resultado = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);


    } catch (PDOException $error){
        echo "Erro:\n" . $error->getMessage();  
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Sua função não retorna nada logo não é possível receber nada na chamada da função, adicione um `return`.

```
$resultado = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
return $resultado;
```

Com a função retornando os registros do banco dedos faça uma atribuição, pois a variáve `$resultado` so existe dentro da função `selecionar_produtos()` depois de sua chamada ele não existe.

```
$produtos = selecionar_produtos();
//código omitido
<?php foreach ($produtos as $key) :?>
```

Comment: Obrigado  pela ajuda :)

Comment: @felipemarques, quando precisar